# Why can I not protect a question?

Tags: support, protected-question

For all the other questions that I checked, I can protect them (20K rep privilege).

I wanted to protect this question (because the same user posted two racist answers within minutes of each other (both were promptly deleted - well done all!)) but there is no protect link for me<sup>1</sup>:

> [Who is the first African/Black superhero?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104732/who-is-the-first-african-black-superhero)

Why do I not see a protect link? I'm using Windows 7 & Google Chrome.

Screenshots: this question, no protect link:

[image: Protect link]

Question with protect link:

[image: Question with protect link]

<sub>1 So I flagged it for the moderators to protect.</sub>

Comment: Not sure why it couldn't be protected but it is now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Because it's too young](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions):

> Which questions can be protected?
>
> Any question at least a day old can be protected and unprotected by users that have the privilege.

There was a [feature-request](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) put in [to allow 15k+ users to protect young questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120572/allow-users-with-15k-reputation-to-protect-questions-less-than-a-day-old-but-wi) back in 2012, but nothing ever came of it; a similar request was [posted in October 2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268353/allow-15k-rep-to-protect-highly-viewed-young-questions).

Comment: Note to self: next to *read the manual*. Nah, that's never going to happen...

Answer (score 10):

Questions have to be at least a day old before you can protect them.

Protection is mostly mean to prevent a flood of *late* poor quality answers, when the question may not otherwise be garnering a lot of attention. I assume that new questions are unprotectable because they expect people to be paying more attention to them.

Comment: Sorry Mike, I could only accept one... :)

Comment: its ok. meta rep doesn't count.